# Showing confirmation "added to shopping cart" in the "add to cart/shopping cart" button

Tags: usability, confirmation, shopping-cart

I'm designing an e-commerce website and I was thinking of a way of showing to a user that the item has been added to the shopping cart.

I'm not sure if my idea is correct but I was thinking of showing a message such as like "added to cart" in the very same button that is used for "add to cart".

You'll find the example in the file attached (don't mind the polish language - it's only the button that matters :) )
[image: Shopping cart CTA]

Does this work? Is it usable? Any better ideas?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: this is very common and used by many ecommerce sites, so you're on the right path

Comment: Thank you. Can you give any examples of websites that use it? Still though, isn't that interrupting the process of adding items to the shopping cart? What if, for example, a user wants to add this item once again but the button already says "Added to cart"? Isn't that confusing? I was thinking of 2 ways:

1st: the confirmation "added to cart" disappears when you click again on the button and then once again the "add to cart" button shows up. 

2nd: The confirmation "added to cart" just shows in the button for 2-3 second after clicking "add to cart" and then fades away back to "add to cart"

Comment: You could show a link or checkbox with "change quantity"

Answer (score 1):

Just change the text of the button to 'Add Another' or 'Add More' to indicate user has already bought this item and he can add more such items if he prefers.

I think ebay or amazon has this type of shopping cart.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. We'll see how the tests go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it's not enough.

Yes, You definitely should tell them that item has been added to cart but also offer them next steps
 - Go to shopping cart
 - Go to checkout
 - Continue shopping